# how to get the text of submit button in php

Tags: php

Hello im having problem of getting the text on submit button . 
what im going to do is use if statement to use a single button to insert and update records. ive found a code in this site but it doesn't give me desired output

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $content) { // Most people refer to $key => $value
       echo "The HTML name: $name <br>";
       echo "The content of it: $content <br>";
    }
```

another problem how do i change the text of the button control using javascript
the code below doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Attach button clicke event hanlder
            $('.btnedit').click(function () {

        var title = document.getElementById('btnsubmit');
        title.innerHTML = "Update";

            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is the code for button

```
<input type="submit"  name="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give name and value to your submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
```

The echo in foreach will be

```
The HTML name: submit
The content of it: SUBMIT
```

To get the value without `foreach()`, you should do like this.

```
echo $_POST['submit'];// will echo SUBMIT
             ^ name of your submit button.
```

**See demo [`HERE`](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/21273/)**

Comment: how to i get the text only of that submit button? without using foreach loop?

Comment: thanks it worked. but how do i change the button text using javascript. i asked it here instead of creating another question. my code worked when i used <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button> but now it doesn't work now im using my javascript code.

Comment: on click of submit button you want to change the text of it??

Comment: document.getElementById("btnsubmit").innerHTML = "Update"; doesn't work anymore

Comment: i tried it the code on fiddle but it doesn't work. why? but on you're example it works

Comment: i added the javascript code can you help me. i can't find the error.

Comment: @knowmeifyou [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/3155/). I have corrected your script.

Comment: it's working fine. i have an edit button inside html html table. every row has a button edit. if i click the edit, the datas from html table copied to text and change the text of the button to update. but so far. changing the button text is not working but all the copying of data's works perfectly

Comment: im changing a button text of another button sir not the text of the button clicked

Comment: @knowmeifyou Glad it helped you.:) Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful